# How to install MuMuDVB

Tags: 14.04

any one knows how can i install MuMuDVB 2.0.0 on ubuntu?

http://mumudvb.net/download/

Comment: which one your choose archive package sir? debian package or source code on github or something sir.

Comment: snapshot section

Comment: https://ftps.crans.org/debian-multimedia/pool/main/m/mumudvb-dmo/

Comment: thank you for attension ,i think i have to install mumudvb_2.0.0-dmo2+bp1_amd64.deb  .how can i install it?

Comment: The nominated duplicate is superficially about ImageMagick, but the overall answer is the same for any application.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1. Install via APT**

According to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&searchon=names&keywords=mumudvb the MuMuDVB package is available for 14.04 via APT.

So simply open up a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mumudvb
```

This should result in version 1.7.1 at the moment.

Regaring different ubuntu-versions:

- 14.04
- 16.04
- 18.04

all featuring mumudvb 1.7.1 right now.

**Option 2: Installing .deb manually:**

In case you are willing to install a local .deb file manually, follow this steps

- On Terminal
- Navigate to the location where your .deb is located
- Enter `sudo dpkg -i NameOfLocalDebFile.deb`

**Option 3: Compile**

If you need a particular newer version consider checking the project website and compile the source yourself.

Comment: i wanna install ver 2.0